# What is the grooviest way to split a Map?

Tags: groovy, hashmap

I need to read from a CSV file into a Map and pass that Map to a backend method, problem is the backend method can choke if the Map is too big. So I need to break up the Map into smaller chunks (partitions) before passing it. Here is what I tried so far..

```
Map ginormousMap = extractMapFromFile()
Map batchedMap = [:]
int index = 0
for ( pair in ginormousMap ) {
    def source = pair.key
    def destination = pair.value

    batchedMap.put(source,destination)
    if(index > 0 && index % 100 == 0 ){
       sendToFragileBackEnd(batchedMap)
       batchedMap = [:]
   }
   index++

}
```

I think at every 100th element this would send the smaller map to the backend and reinitialize it.

Would this work? Is there a better way?

Comment: Is it a map? Sure it's not a list of maps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An easy way for doing that is by using the **collate()** method.

**collate()** method enables division of a list into sub-lists of a specified size.

In case the collection is a Map (as it is in your situation) you can convert the Map.keySet() into List and than execute the **collate()** method.

```
Map fullMap = [a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7]

(fullMap.keySet() as List).collate(3).each{
    def map = fullMap.subMap(it)
    println map
}
```

or in your code...

```
Map ginormousMap = extractMapFromFile()

(ginormousMap.keySet() as List).collate(100).each{
    sendToFragileBackEnd(ginormousMap.subMap(it))
}
```

Comment: I should probably have added that collate splits a list into a list of lists, the size of which is determined by the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this:

```
Map ginormousMap = extractMapFromFile()
(ginormousMap.size()/100).times { i ->
       sendToFragileBackEnd(ginormousMap[i*100..(i+1)*100-1)
}
```

I'm sure this will not work out of the box and it is not beautiful, but I guess you see the idea behind it :-)

Comment: I like your suggestion, would you mind cleaning it so it would work out of the box? Thanks!

Comment: seems to be too late for me 